# MVC 4 Binding and returning user edits

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am currently working through my first ASP.MVC4 project in VS2012 and I was wondering how you handle the binding of data to textboxes and combo boxes (Select blocks) then how you return the results back to the controller?

**Model**

```
Public Class OpenBuildFaultsViewModel

    Public Property FailureID As Int64
    Public Property ModelName As String
    Public Property ZoneName As String
    Public Property Fault As String
    Public Property FaultCode As String
    Public Property FaultCodeDetail As String
    Public Property FaultArea As String
    Public Property MajorAssembly As String
    Public Property SubAssembly As String
    Public Property ComponentAssembly As String
    Public Property BusinessTest As String
    Public Property AuditScore As String
    Public Property Comment As String
    Public Property ShortagePart As String
    Public Property CreatedBy As String
    Public Property FixedByID As Int32
    Public Property FixedByComment As String
    Public Property FixedByFaultRectificationID As Int32

End Class


Public Class RectificationCodesViewModel

    Friend Property ID As Long
    Friend Property Description As String

End Class
```

**Controller** ( Failure SignOff Methods)

```
Namespace QSmartRectification

    Public Class FailuresController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Function FailureSignOff() As ActionResult

            Dim failureID As Int64 = Convert.ToInt64(TempData("FailureID"))

            Dim data As IEnumerable(Of OpenBuildFaultsViewModel) = Session("Failures")
            Dim model = data.Where(Function(w) w.FailureID.Equals(failureID))

            Dim codes As IEnumerable(Of RectificationCodesViewModel) = TryCast(Session("RectificationCodes"), IEnumerable(Of RectificationCodesViewModel))

            If codes IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim recCodes = From c In codes
                                Select New SelectListItem With {.Value = c.ID, .Text = c.Description}
                ViewBag.RectificationCodes = recCodes
            End If

            Return View(model.FirstOrDefault)

        End Function

        ' POST: /Failures/FailureSignOff
        <HttpPost> _
        Function FailureSignOff(model As OpenBuildFaultsViewModel) As ActionResult

            Stop

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**View**

```
@ModelType QSmartRectification.OpenBuildFaultsViewModel

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Failure Sign Off"
End Code
@section featured
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper" >
            <p class="site-title float-left">QSmart Rectification Sign Off</p>
            <input type="image" src="../../Images/Product.png" />
        </div>
    </section>
End Section
<br />
@Using Html.BeginForm()
@Html.ValidationSummary()  
    @<fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend>Fault Sign Off</legend>
            <section class="contentdetail">
                <section class="block">
                    <div class="divHeader">
                        <div class="float-left" >
                            <img alt="Missing Image" src="@String.Format("../../Images/{0}.png", Model.MajorAssembly)"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divHeaderOffset">
                            <div class="float-left divHalfSpace">
                                <label class="header">Major Assembly</label>
                                <label>@Model.MajorAssembly</label>
                                <label class="header">Sub Assembly</label>
                                <label>@Model.SubAssembly</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="float-left divHalfSpace">
                                <label class="header">Component Assembly</label>
                                <label>@Model.ComponentAssembly</label> 
                                <label class="header">Business Test</label>
                                <label>@Model.BusinessTest</label> 
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <fieldset class="fieldset">
                        <legend>Fix Details</legend>
                        <div class="divDetailMargin">
                            <div class="float-left divHalfSpace">
                                <label class="header">Rectification Code</label>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.FixedByFaultRectificationID, ViewBag.RectificationCodes))
                            </div>
                            <div class="float-left divHalfSpace">
                                <label class="header">Rectification Comment</label>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(x) x.FixedByComment, 4)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="divButtonHeader">
                        <div class="divThreeColumns">
                        </div>
                        <div class="divThreeColumns">
                            <input id="FixFault" type="submit" value=""/>
                            <input id="Back" type="button" value="" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Failures")'" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="divThreeColumns">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </section>
    </fieldset>
End Using
```

The POST in the controller currently returns an empty model with the exception being the FixedByFaultRectificationID and FixedByComment which are populated correctly from the selected Combo item and TextAreaFor in the View.

```
' POST: /Failures/FailureSignOff
<HttpPost> _
Function FailureSignOff(model As OpenBuildFaultsViewModel) As ActionResult

    Stop

End Function
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
Following some further investigation into MVC and model binding I have resolved this problem. After refactoring the code to pass some of the data into the view using the ViewBag and binding the view data via the ViewBag I can pass a simpler model to the View.

The reason that the model was not being returned in the HTTPPost action was that not all item in the model were bound up in the view as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388581/passing-object-back-to-view-in-httppost) post.

**Working View**

```
@ModelType QSmartRectification.OpenBuildFaultsViewModel

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Failure Sign Off"
End Code
@section featured
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper" >
            <p class="site-title float-left">QSmart Rectification Sign Off</p>
            <input type="image" src="../../Images/Product.png" />
        </div>
    </section>
End Section
<br />
@Using Html.BeginForm()
@Html.ValidationSummary()  
    @<fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend>Fault Sign Off</legend>
            <section class="contentdetail">
                <section class="block">
                    <div class="divHeader">
                        <div class="float-left" >
                            <img alt="Missing Image" src="@String.Format("../../Images/{0}.png", Model.MajorAssembly)"/>
                        </div>

                        @Html.Hidden("FailureID", Model.FailureID)
                        @Html.Hidden("ModelName", Model.ModelName)
                        @Html.Hidden("ZoneName", Model.ZoneName)
                        @Html.Hidden("Fault", Model.Fault)
                        @Html.Hidden("FaultCode", Model.FaultCode)
                        @Html.Hidden("FaultCodeDetail", Model.FaultCodeDetail)
                        @Html.Hidden("FaultArea", Model.FaultArea)
                        @Html.Hidden("AuditScore", Model.AuditScore)
                        @Html.Hidden("Comment", Model.Comment)
                        @Html.Hidden("ShortagePart", Model.ShortagePart)
                        @Html.Hidden("CreatedBy", Model.CreatedBy)
                        @Html.Hidden("FixedByID",model.FixedByID)

                        <div class="divHeaderOffset">
                            <div class="float-left divHalfSpace">
                                <label class="header">Major Assembly</label>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.MajorAssembly, New With {.ReadOnly = True})
                                <label class="header">Sub Assembly</label>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.SubAssembly, New With {.ReadOnly = True})
                            </div>
                            <div class="float-left divHalfSpace">
                                <label class="header">Component Assembly</label>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.ComponentAssembly, New With {.ReadOnly = True})
                                <label class="header">Business Test</label>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.BusinessTest, New With {.ReadOnly = True})
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <fieldset class="fieldset">
                        <legend>Fix Details</legend>
                        <div class="divDetailMargin">
                            <div class="float-left divHalfSpace">
                                <label class="header">Rectification Code</label>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.FixedByFaultRectificationID, ViewBag.RectificationCodes)
                            </div>
                            <div class="float-left divHalfSpace">
                                <label class="header">Rectification Comment</label>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(x) x.FixedByComment, 4)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="divButtonHeader">
                        <div class="divThreeColumns">
                        </div>
                        <div class="divThreeColumns">
                            <input id="FixFault" type="submit" value=""/>
                            <input id="Back" type="button" value="" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Failures")'" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="divThreeColumns">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </section>
    </fieldset>
End Using
```

**Working Controller**

```
Namespace QSmartRectification

    Public Class FailuresController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Function FailureSignOff() As ActionResult

            Dim failureID As Int64 = Convert.ToInt64(TempData("FailureID"))

            Dim data As IEnumerable(Of OpenBuildFaultsViewModel) = Session("Failures")
            Dim model = data.Where(Function(w) w.FailureID.Equals(failureID))

            Dim codes As IEnumerable(Of RectificationCodesViewModel) = TryCast(Session("RectificationCodes"), IEnumerable(Of RectificationCodesViewModel))

            If codes IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim recCodes = From c In codes
                                Select New SelectListItem With {.Value = c.ID, .Text = c.Description}
                ViewBag.RectificationCodes = recCodes
            End If

            Return View(DirectCast(model.FirstOrDefault, OpenBuildFaultsViewModel))

        End Function

        ' POST: /Failures/FailureSignOff
        <HttpPost> _
        Function FailureSignOff(model As OpenBuildFaultsViewModel) As ActionResult

            Stop

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Making theses changes the view is correctly populated back to the controller on the HTTPPost.

[image: Returned Model]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `ReadOnly` keyword from the `Failure` property.

`Public ReadOnly Property Failure As OpenBuildFaultsViewModel`

I think the model binder won't be able to set the property since readonly properties can only be set in the declaration or constructor of a class.

Comment: Thanks for the response Francois but that didn't fix the problem.